# Why is the dynamic mean-variance problem time-inconsistent?

Tags: mean-variance, dynamic

A lot of the literature in dynamic mean-variance problem states that the dynamic mean-variance problem is time-inconsistent. Now I was not able to find an example of why the problem is time inconsistent that is easy enough to digest. So the question is: why is the dynamic mean-variance problem time-inconsistent?

Comment: usually ( can't say for sure in this case ) it's because your optimizing statically and hoping that what you are optimizing over doesn't change in the future.  for example, with mean variance framework, suppose you are optimizing over two periods. So, you have the means and variances at time t = 0. ( assume, they stay the same during period 1 ). What you are assuming is that the means and variance also aren't going to change in period 2. If they do, then you have a time-inconsistent problem.

Comment: I can't go into details in a comment but time-inconsistency can also be related to bellman optimality. If you're familiar with dynamic programming, it is based on the concept of bellman optimality. The time inconsistency problem can also arise because bellman optimality doesn't hold in the case where there are forward looking expectations that change over time. But a simple example of that is the example I used in the first comment. It gets more complicated in other frameworks but the concept is the same.

Comment: As explained by @mark leeds, time-inconsistency tends to arise if the optimization problem doesn't satisfy the Bellman principle. Essentially minimizing $Var_0(W_T)$ the unconditional variance of terminal wealth from the point of view of the initial period and some later date is generally different.